# Overwrite a portion of a file w/o modification to the unmodified content

Tags: files, dd

I'd basically like to create an allocated file lets say 1GB with content.  Then hopefully using some command line utility I'd like to overwrite-in-place a portion of the file, lets say the beginning 4 MB ONLY leaving the rest of the file contents in-tact.  I've checked cp, and dd but they don't seem to have anything like this.  Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place and/or not understanding the implications of some of the options.

Yes, I could generate a C program to do this but my preference for portability is to use a command line situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `dd if=some-new-data of=your-big-file obs=1 seek=0 count=4M` or so?

Comment: @Lucas: Nope - truncates the big file (i.e. of=)

Comment: `conv=notrunc` to the rescue?

Comment: Well, I just tried it myself and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example with `dd`:

```
$ cat data
insertion goes here: <...>

$ cat insert
ABC 123 XYZ

$ dd if=insert skip=4 count=3 of=data seek=22 bs=1 conv=notrunc
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3 bytes transferred in 0.001 secs (2918 bytes/sec)

$ cat data
insertion goes here: <123>
```

The `dd` command that I've used here skips 4 blocks into the input file and then reads 3 blocks. The blocks are written to the output file after seeking 22 blocks into it.  The output is not truncated. One block is one byte.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
$ echo aaaaaaaaaa > a
$ echo bbbbbbbbbb > b
$ dd if=a of=b conv=notrunc ibs=1 obs=1 seek=3 count=4
$ cat b
bbbaaaabbb
```